# Is it possible to create an Oracle 11g database using an Oracle 10g ASM instance?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

Is it possible to create an Oracle 11g database using an Oracle 10g ASM instance?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run Oracle 11g instance that connects to Oracle 10g ASM instance. 
The only problem for you could be clusterware version. Oracle CRS should have highest version among (ASM,RDBMS).

And because ASM version will stay 10g, RDBMS will not be able to use any new ASM features.

More information can be found in Metalink article "Oracle Clusterware - ASM - Database Version Compatibility [ID 337737.1]"